# Web scraping using urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, rss, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to scrape all the titles off of this RSS Feed:

http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/rss

This is my code for the same:

```
import urllib2
import re
content = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/rss').read()
allTitles =  re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
list = re.findall(allTitles,content)
for e in range(0, 2):
    print list[e]
```

However, instead of getting a list of titles as the output, I am getting a bunch of code from the rss source. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use non-greedy mark (?) in expression:

```
#allTitles =  re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
allTitles =  re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>')
```

Without `?` all text except last `</title>` placed in (.*) group...

Comment: I just get the first 2 titles extracted from that link if I put the non-greedy mark in my code. How can I extract all the text embedded under <title></title> ?

Comment: Ohh yes! My bad. Thanks for such a precise and prompt answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, your code lacks greedy specifier for regexp, and can be fixed with it. But I strongly recommend switching from regular expressions to tools, more suited for xml parsing, such as [lxml](http://lxml.de/), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or specialised rss parsing modules such as [feedparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser).

For example, see how your task can be done with lxml:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> rss = lxml.etree.fromstring(content)
>>> titles = rss.findall('.//title')
>>> print '\n'.join(title.text for title in titles[:2])
Questions About Python (programming language) on Quora
Could someone explain for me the following Python function that uses @wraps from functools?
```